# Calculate using loop in R

Tags: r, loops

Consider the following data frames:

```
x1 <- matrix(c(100,200,300,500),ncol=1,dimnames=list(LETTERS[1:4],"x"))
y1 <- matrix(c(75,100,300,400),ncol=1,dimnames=list(LETTERS[1:4],"y"))
datamichael <- data.frame(x1,y1)
x2 <- matrix(c(200,50,200,600),ncol=1,dimnames=list(LETTERS[1:4],"x"))
y2 <- matrix(c(100,100,400,300),ncol=1,dimnames=list(LETTERS[1:4],"y"))
dataewan <- data.frame(x2,y2)
x3 <- matrix(c(100,150,400,200),ncol=1,dimnames=list(LETTERS[1:4],"x"))
y3 <- matrix(c(100,100,400,300),ncol=1,dimnames=list(LETTERS[1:4],"y"))
datatom <- data.frame(x3,y3)
```

I have merged these three data.frame by:

```
datamichaeldataewan <- rbind(datamichael,dataewan)
datamichaeldatatom <- rbind(datamichael,datatom)
```

By using the package `Benchmarking` I want to make the following calculation:

```
library(Benchmarking)
effmichaelewan <- dea(data.frame(datamichaeldataewan[1]),
                      data.frame(datamichaeldataewan[2]),
                      RTS="crs", ORIENTATION="out",
                      XREF=datamichael$x1, YREF=datamichael$y1)
effmichaeltom <- dea(data.frame(datamichaeldatatom[1]),
                     data.frame(datamichaeldatatom[2]),
                     RTS="crs", ORIENTATION="out",
                     XREF=datamichael$x1, YREF=datamichael$y1)
```

The problem in my case is that I have a lot more than two merged data.frame. So is it possible to make the calculation above by using a loop? The important is that the name of the output variable is "eff[name-after-first-data][name-after-second-data]". And that: `datamichaeldataewan` change within each calculation:

```
dea(data.frame(datamichaeldataewan[1]),
    data.frame(datamichaeldataewan[2]),
    RTS="crs", ORIENTATION="out",
    XREF=datamichael$x1, YREF=datamichael$y1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store your merged dataframes in a list this can be easily rewritten.

Store `dataframe`s in a `list` and `rbind` with `datamichael` using `lapply`:

```
datalist <- list(dataewan = dataewan, datatom = datatom)
datalist <- lapply(datalist, function(x) rbind(datamichael, x))
names(datalist) <- paste0("datamichael", names(datalist))
```

Calculate results with `lapply`:

```
efflist <- lapply(datalist, function(x) 
  dea(data.frame(x[1]), data.frame(x[2]), RTS="crs", ORIENTATION="out", 
      XREF=datamichael$x1, YREF=datamichael$y1)) 
names(efflist) <- paste0("eff", gsub("data", "", names(efflist)))

efflist
# $effmichaelewan
#     A     B     C     D    A1    B1    C1    D1 
# 2.667 4.000 2.000 2.500 4.000 1.000 1.000 4.000 
# 
# $effmichaeltom
#     A     B     C     D    A1    B1    C1    D1 
# 2.000 3.000 1.500 1.875 1.500 2.250 1.500 1.000
```